# Chrome redirect URL

Tags: google-chrome, redirection, url

Is there a way to force chrome to redirect certain websites? Preferably without extension. I want to do someting like

> www.website.com/es/whatever -> www-website.com/us/whatever

and something like

> www.old-website.com -> www.new-website.com

using google I'll only find virus fixes and unwanted redirects people try to surpress

Comment: Short answer: No.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome (as of 66.0.3359.139) doesn't have a built-in redirect tool. If you find viruses looking for extensions like this, access the official [Chrome Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/).